# Unable to execute component's function inside scroll event listener Angular 4

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, angularjs-directive

I trying to execute a function inside a scroll listener. Following is my scroll listener code

```
 @HostListener("window:scroll", [])
  onWindowScroll() {
    this.updatePageNumber();
  }
```

and following is function i am trying to call inside the onWindowScroll function

```
updatePageNumber() {
    this.pageNumber = this.canvasHandler.getPageNumber($(window).scrollTop());
  }
```

but upon loading page the page is just stuck and tab becomes not-responsive. I have tried the same thing with jquery as well but behaviour is same i.e app stops responding.

Comment: use `window.scrollY`. 
`var y = window.scrollY`

Comment: @SuganthanMadhavanPillai i have tried window.scrollY but it does not solves the problem.

Comment: window.scrollY should work. But have you declared $ in the component file that it gets responsive? Have you done a console.log of how many times the event-listener is being triggered or a console.log on ngOnChanges()? I possibly see a loop here.